# How to load a shell app?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I created a shell app that started out as aliases and got out of hand.

The "app" provides shell functions that call  yt-dlp, a video downloader, and organizes the downloads in a solid directory structure.

I currently load the app with one line in `bash.bashrc`, the `.bashrc` equivalent in Termux (terminal emulator for Android).

The one line in `bash.bashrc` that loads the shell app

`. /path/to/main`

`main` loads up the rest and its contents looks like this

```
. "$bin_dir/vars"
. "$bin_dir/common"
. "$bin_dir/logger"
. "$bin_dir/history"
. "$bin_dir/files"
. "$bin_dir/dlv"
. "$bin_dir/fvid"
```

These are all bash scripts that expose functions and variables to the terminal, making them available to the user. The loading order is important, `dlv` depends on stuff in `common` for example.

Now I'd like to open source the project and make it easy to install. I wonder if I can load the shell app without an entry in `bash.bashrc`.

I thought about putting the scripts in `$PREFIX/bin/` but then if someone calls `dlv`, all other dependencies haven't loaded.

I could throw everything in one file but my intention was to create these modules to keep the code tidy.

I guess without a more elegant solution, I could write an `install.sh` that does `echo ". /path/to/main" >> ~/bash.bashrc`...  Thoughts?

Edit: I put main (loader) in `$PREFIX/bin` but when I run the command, none of the functions and variables are available in my shell. I did not expect that.

Comment: Adding this to `.bashrc` will start your "app" everytime a shell is started - I don't think that's what you want, is it?

Comment: @Panki It is what I want because it only loads functions and variables to be used by the user. It doesn't actually do work at load time.

Comment: But as a user of your app, do I want this to happen? Do I want this to run every time I start a new shell? Wouldn't it be more sensible to have the user run something like `app-init` first?

Comment: That's probably a good idea. Put main under bin and have main load the rest of the scripts in /opt perhaps? One can still add main to .bashrc if they want.

Comment: It'd help to know what your app is supposed to be doing in detail - please add that in the OP

Comment: @Panki I edited the OP.

Comment: Are you using the Termux widget add on? If so, you could create a launcher script in `~/.shortcuts` that runs `bash -i --rcfile /path/to/main` and you should get an interactive bash prompt with the functions in those files pre-sourced, without modifying the default Termux settings. (BTW, please learn what the word "boot" means.) Don't mess up the default `.bashrc`.

Comment: @frabjous I didn't know about that. It's definitely usable. P.S. changed the boot words in the OP. I guess boot only applies to the OS booting up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to drop the need to be able to run `main` and run `source main` instead.

It's not clear to me why just running `main`, which contains `source` commands, doesn't work but this workaround is not too bad.

By putting `main` in `$PREFIX/bin`, the OS can find `main` in `$PATH`. This will work on all Termux installs as `$PREFIX/bin` is in Termux `$PATH` by default.